# Android: Error handling onClickListener

Tags: android, android-activity, android-event

I have some activity handling the click event on any view

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    ...
}
```

I have tried to override via this

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button1:
            mp.start();  
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            mp.pause();  
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            mp.stop();  
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

But it is asking me to change to handle click event via

```
@Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
```

Has the api's changed , what is the issue I dont have any idea about ?

Comment: What is your import statements

Comment: import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

and not

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

See this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html